# Intersection Polygon-PolyLine with pyqgis

Tags: pyqgis

I want to make intersection between polygon and polyline shapefile with pyqgis, but I get an empty output. Here the code that i use :

```
params = {'INPUT': polygone.shp, 'OVERLAY': line.shp, 'INPUT_FIELDS': [], 'OVERLAY_FIELDS': [], 'OUTPUT': 'memory'}
processing.run('native:intersection', params)
```

bellow the picture of polygon and polyline shapefile. The both shapefiles have the same crs : epsg:2154

[image]

Comment: Please [Edit] the question to specify the coordinate references of the two files.

Comment: @Vince i edited it

Comment: @Joseph - Thanks, it work.

Comment: @Elite - Most welcome, glad it helped!

Answer (score 1):

Create a **buffer** of the line layer and use that as the overlay layer instead.